# How to add multiple column foreign key on one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I want to add multiple foreign key constraint on one column. How it is possible?

Here is my tables structure:

**languges**

```
--------------------------------
- id  |  code |  name  |  name -
--------------------------------
```

**countries**

```
---------------------------------------------
- id  |  country_id |  language_id  |  name -
---------------------------------------------
```

**cities**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
- id  |  city_id |  language_id  |  country_id  |  name -
---------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to do? For example:
If I have country France and city Paris my tables shold look like this:

**countries**

```
---------------------------------------------
- id  |  country_id |  language_id  |  name -
---------------------------------------------
   1        1             1           France
   2        1             2           საფრანგ
```

**cities**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
- id  |  city_id |  language_id  |  country_id  |  name -
---------------------------------------------------------
   1        1             1             1         Paris
   2        1             2             1         პარიზი
```

So, as you can see every country has unique ID (Auto Increment) column and (own_id, language_id) unique pair.
How to add foreign key constraint to reference (language_id, own_id) unique column?
How is it possible?
Do I have to add only (own_id) `references on other tables id` foreign key?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There are two ways to achieve the task.Create a stored procedure that accepts country name and city name as input. Logic should be written to insert to countries and cities table for the languages from languages table. The table definition should have auto_increment on the id column. Alternatively you can create triggers on the table as well to achieve the same.

Comment: I 'll try that  now

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES parent_table (p1);`

is that what you want?

Comment: No that's not what I want, this is simple foreign key constraint